# how define custom shortcut in ubuntu to change keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, input-language

in windows, shortcut to change keyboard layout is *Alt+Shift*. in previous versions of Ubuntu it was available to select this shortcut for changing layout. but in recent Ubuntu versions it is not available. in Ubuntu 21.10 when i select *Customize Shortcuts* in settings it does not accept *Alt+Shift* as a shortcut.
is there any conflict between my preferred shortcut and Ubuntu default shortcuts cause this problem?
how can i overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To assign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> for switching keyboard layouts, you will need to install Gnome Tweaks. In Tweaks, go to the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab and then click the "Additional Layout Options" button. In the dialog that appears, open the section "Switching to another layout" and select "Alt+Shift" there.

For your information, independent from the above, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is already configured by default to switch to another keyboard layout in Ubuntu. That shortcut key can be changed in "Settings" - "Keyboard", section "Typing".

Comment: i know all these. i want to change super+space to Alt+Shift. i want it to be the same as windows. but ubuntu does not accept Alt+Shift.